# Upcast and then downcast a record C#

Tags: c#, .net, casting

Imagine the following record classes

```
public abstract record Employee
{
  public int EmployeeId {get; init;}
}

---

public record Manager: Employee
{
  public string AdminCode { get; init; }
}

---

public record Trainee : Employee
{
  public int Managerid {get; init; }
}
```

Now, assume I have a trainee, object that I'd like to create a manager object out of.  Of course I can map the fields one at a time, but in real life, I have *much* bigger objects.  If these were classes this would be a non-starter but with neat syntax like `with`, we can do some cool stuff to create copies of records in C#.

What I want to do, but don't know how to (pesudo-code):

```
private Boss PromoteTrainee(Trainee trainee, string adminCode)
{
  return (trainee as Employee as Manager) with { AdminCode = adminCode };
}
```

This of course does not work because the second `as` cast fails and comes up with null.  Is there a way to do this which doesn't require manually copying the EmployeeId (and all the other fields that might be on my base object)?

**EDIT: Misleading example I think **

My real life example is that I have a bunch of json contracts and DTO objects for them.  Many of the objects share a TON of the same fields (which don't change but if they did, they'd always change together), so I created a base record to hold those fields so I don't have to duplicate them across the objects.

I've because I prefer immutable objects for DTOs, I use `record` types with `init` on the properties instead of `set`.  This however limits my code to only be able to set the properties at creation time using object initializers (or constructors with the other record syntax).

So if I've already got the logic to create a Trainee DTO with all of their trainee fields and Employee base fields, how can I reuse that setup logic for a Manager DTO changing the parts that set the Manager DTO field without duplicating a ton of code?

Comment: Inheritance is the wrong design decision for your use case. Whether they're a manager, a trainee, or whatever is a label (or property) applied to the person. You don't kill someone and regrow a new person when they've been promoted (unless, perhaps, they're a Vorta), but that's what you're modeling here.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking "but this employee *is-a* manager" but actually that employee "*has-a* manager's level of experience and responsibility".

Comment: Why are your examples `record` and not `class`? You don't appear to be using much of the features of `record`.

Comment: See edit -- these comments have revealed that my example was too simplistic and not effectively representative of my real life situation.

Comment: I think you should be using [positional parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#positional-syntax-for-property-definition) to a primary constructor, which will automatically declare corresponding positional properties.

Comment: Also, I assume `Boss` was meant to be `Manager`?

Comment: *"Many of the objects share a TON of the same fields"* - consider using AutoMapper to make shorter work of translating between them.

Comment: I don't think AutoMapper is the tool I want here, in order to use automapper to set readonly properties in the constructor, I have to explicitly list them out I think, kinda defeats the purpose.  Besides, unless i'm missing something AutoMapper is predominately Reflection under the hood, which is what my small foreach solution is.  How does automapper do better than that?

Comment: These are DTOs. You you don't need constructor parameters or read/init-only properties. What NetMage suggested doesn't apply to DTOs. They just hold values for transfer. They don't need to deal with invariants and such.

Comment: AutoMapper doesn't need you to list all properties explicitly unless you configure it that way, and then as far as I'm concerned, that defeats the purpose of being an "auto mapper". If you're concerned about the performance of reflection and/or expression trees, maybe it's not for you. It was only a suggestion. But measure, first. It's probably not as bad as you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution that "works" though it might be somewhat hacky, it does solve my problem.

```
public record Manager : Employee
{
    public Manager(Employee fromBase)
    {
        var props = typeof(Employee).GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(this, 
               propertyInfo.GetValue(fromBase));
        }
    }

    public string AdminCode { get; init; }
}
```

This allows to construct an instance of Trainee (or Employee if abstract isn't a requirement), and use it to construct an instance of Manager with all the properties copied like so:

```
var manager = new Manager(trainee){ AdminCode = "1234" };
```

Comment: If you are going to do this, I would suggest at least caching the `props` in a static variable so you don't have to run through `GetProperties` every time you use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `record`, you should take advantage of positional parameters and primary constructors:

```
public abstract record Employee(int EmployeeId) {
}

public record Manager(int EmployeeID, string AdminCode) : Employee(EmployeeID) {
}

public record Trainee(int EmployeeId, int Managerid) : Employee(EmployeeId) {
}

private Manager PromoteTrainee(Trainee trainee, string adminCode)
    => new Manager(trainee.EmployeeId, adminCode);
```

If you have a lot of properties in `Employee`, and want to avoid copying them around, perhaps `record` isn't the right solution. Your `Manager` and `Trainee` could share an interface with `Employee` or have a property that contains the `Employee` that it describes.

Answer (score 0):

Is composition a way you can go?

Try this:

```
public interface IEmployee
{
    int EmployeeId { get; }
}

public record Employee : IEmployee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; init; }
}

public record Manager : IEmployee
{
    public string AdminCode { get; init; }

    private IEmployee _employee;

    public Manager(IEmployee employee)
    {
        _employee = employee;
    }
    
    public int EmployeeId => _employee.EmployeeId;

    public Trainee Demote(int managerId) =>
        new Trainee(_employee) { ManagerId = managerId};
}

public record Trainee : IEmployee
{
    public int ManagerId { get; init; }

    private IEmployee _employee;

    public Trainee(IEmployee employee)
    {
        _employee = employee;
    }

    public int EmployeeId => _employee.EmployeeId;

    public Manager Promote(string adminCode) =>
        new Manager(_employee) { AdminCode = adminCode };
}
```

Then your code is almost exactly like the pseudo-code you suggested:

```
Trainee trainee = new Trainee(new Employee() { EmployeeId = 42 })
{
    ManagerId = 101
};
Manager manager = trainee.Promote("AdminCodeHere");
```

Comment: I appreciate the creativity here, but this implementation would require listing each and every one of Employee's fields explicitly in both the Manager and Trainee class